# Python - adding an element to a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Working with a json file in my python program. I need to modify the json file from within a function to add an empty "placeholder" element. I just want to add an empty element for a key contained in the convID object. Does the json library allow for a simpler way to append an element to a json file?

example.json:

```
{"1005672": "Testing needles note", "1005339": "Reply", "988608": "Received the message"}
```

I would like this to happen (*convID* denotes the key stored in convID object):

```
{"1005672": "Testing needles note", "1005339": "Reply", "988608": "Received the message", "*convID*": "none"}
```

I'm guessing I will have to load the json into a dictionary object, make the modifications and write it back to the file... but this is proving difficult for me as I am still learning. Here's my swing at it:

```
def updateJSON():
   jsonCache={} # type: Dict

   with open(example.json) as j:
      jsonCache=json.load(j)

   *some code to make append element modification

    with open('example.json', 'w') as k:
       k.write(jsonCache)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a key to a dict, you simply name it:

```py
your_dict['convID'] = 'convID_value'
```

So, your code would be something like:

```py
import json

# read a file, or get a string
your_json = '{"1005672": "Testing needles note", "1005339": "Reply", "988608": "Received the message"}'

your_dict = json.loads(your_json)

your_dict['convID'] = 'convID_value'
```

So, using it with your code, it will be:

```py
def update_json():
    json_cache = {}

    with open('example.json', 'r') as j:
        json_cache = json.load(j)

    json_cache['convID'] = 'the value you want'

    with open('example.json', 'w') as k:
        json.dump(json_cache, f)
```

Comment: Please use PEP8 guidelines for code snippet in Python.

Comment: last line needs a k instead of an f, but that worked... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Please use PEP8 style guidelines.

Following code piece would work

import json

```
def update_json():
    with open('example.json', 'r') as file:
        json_cache = json.load(file)
        json_cache['convID'] = None
    with open('example.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(json_cache, file)
```

Comment: json.load(file) and json.dump(json_cache, file) would be smarter :)

Comment: @SvenEberth Updated my answer :)